# Old HTTPS domain needs to direct to new domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

So, my client changed their old domain to a new domain which had an SSL cert on it. The old domain is indexed as https://olddomain.com and even though I changed the forwarding in Godaddy to go to the new domain it will not load!
I'm trying to redirect with a htaccess file but I have not had any success. So,
https://olddomain.com does not redirect but if you type in
olddomain.com it redirects.

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to get the https://olddomain.com to redirect? FYI: I do not have hosting setup for the old domain.

My htaccess file is just this:

```
 RewriteEngine On 
 RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R,L]

 RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} \olddomain.com$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$  https://www.newdomain.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 2 rules can be combined into one and `\olddomain.com$` is incorrect regex because of `\o`

Try this rule:

```
 RewriteEngine On 

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} olddomain\.com$ [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteRule ^ https://www.newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you both but the old https:// olddaomin.com is still not redirecting. It's just getting "This webpage is not available."

Comment: Is `olddaomin.com` still a valid address? Can you ping it? I also corrected my typo so try edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as `HTTPS_HOST`, see [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) for a list of available variables.

You have `HTTP_HOST` or `HTTPS` available. If you want to redirect to `https://newdomain.com`, you can just check for `olddomain.com`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} olddomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  https://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Don't forget the slash, because in a `.htaccess` context, the leading slash is removed. Otherwise, `http://olddomain.com/page.html` would be redirected to `https://www.newdomain.compage.html`. Not exactky what you would expect.

Never test with `301` enabled, see this answer [Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542) for details.